Glide - Retrieve file path for cached bitmap
How to get filepath to cached bitmap ?
When loading from url like below, I'm able to get filePath to the cached image
var obj = Glide.With(this)
             .Load("url")
             .Submit()
             .Get();
if (obj is Java.IO.File file) 
{
    using var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
    handler.Post(() =>
    {
       Glide.With(this)
            .Load(file)
            .SetDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.All)
            .Downsample(DownsampleStrategy.CenterInside)
            .Listener(this)
            .Into(imageView);
    });
}
   

But how to get filepath for bitmap when loading a bitmap like below ?
Bitmap bitmap = //populate bitmap
var obj = Glide.With(this)
                .Load(bitmap)
                .Submit()
                .Get();
//obj is a Bitmap here
 using var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
 handler.Post(() =>
 {
    Glide.With(this)
         .Load(obj)
         .SetDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.All)
         .Downsample(DownsampleStrategy.CenterInside)
         .Listener(this)
         .Into(imageView);
 });


Do you want path to bitmap as ur are getting for the Url ?

@GauravBharadia Yes :)

There is no path to a bitmap, you have to save it to cache or storage to get file

@GauravBharadia But don't I save it by .SetDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.All) ? Or how do I save it to cache?

It only applies to url image links as far as i know. Bitmap is on the RAM not in storage so first save it then you will get its path.
